# Ubuntu scanning internet traffic?

Tags: traffic

Can Ubuntu scann all internet traffic in my office? I have 10 employees with Windows desktops and I would like to know which internet websites are they visiting.

I have Ubuntu desktop 13.04 at this moment installed on my old desktop PC.

How can I set up this?

Comment: Depends on whether you want to do this "on the sly" or install applications on each computer or setup a proxy and make all users point to the proxy to route their web traffic.

Comment: On the sly, definitley...

Comment: you need to set your lan card in promiscuous mode and then start wireshark without that your lan card wont intercept all the traffic I am assuming that you are the gateway for the entire network because if that is not the case then I am afraid it is not possible

Answer (score 3):

If you do this on the sly your best option is to use Wireshark. This program can scan every packet on your network and then you filter the results on the HTTP protocol.

```
sudo apt-get install wireshark
```

That installs the program. As its a very popular program you will find many guides on the internet using this program.

Look at this for an example https://serverfault.com/questions/96272/how-to-filter-http-traffic-in-wireshark

PS: Based on laws in certain countries, "on the sly", can be illegal

Comment: I know about Wireshark... Can you tell me how can I see visited websites? I couldn't find it in manual/documentation, so I gave up...

Comment: @Tomislav you need to set a filter on port 80 after you have scanned the network for a few hours. Each port 80 packet will have a GET command inside it with the URL as part of that packet